# When should I override superclass's methods in a subclass? Must all superclass's methods be overridden if there are no extra functionality?

Tags: java

I have a superclass and subclasses that inherits the superclass. The superclass contains 6 methods but my subclasses only have a different implementation of 1 of the superclass's methods which needs to be overridden. Do I still have to override the remaining 5 methods in the subclass by doing, ie;

```java
@Override
public void someMethod(String someString) {
    super.someMethod(someString);
}
```

I feel like it's redundant to do so but when calling someMethod in the subclass, will it execute the superclass's methods if it's not overridden or will there be an error? I'm not sure what's good programming practice as I'm new to Java.

Comment: override what you must, inherit what you can.

Comment: It depends on the type of Superclass, if it's an `Abstract` class you must override all your method. For concrete class, you only have to override what is required. And this is the fundamental of `OOPs` that your superclass's methods can be used by subclass.

Comment: @darshgohel, *if it's an Abstract class you must override all your method* Not really, you must override only those methods which don't have implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to override other methods if you do not change their implementation, that's what inheritance means. And this is a good practice of reusing your code to avoid repeating yourself.

> when calling someMethod in subclass, will it execute the superclass's
>   methods if it's not overridden or will there be an error?

Yes, it will. No error will be thrown unless the method you call is visible to subclasses.

Comment: I disagree, that inheritance is a good practice for code reusage. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @Andronicus, we're not choosing between composition and inheritance here. There're prons and cons of both methods. Inheritance *can* help with avoiding code repetition, and that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

As per official [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html),

> The ability of a subclass to override a method allows a class to inherit from a superclass whose behavior is "close enough" and then to modify behavior as needed. The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides. An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant return type.
>
> When overriding a method, you might want to use the @Override
>   annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a
>   method in the superclass. If, for some reason, the compiler detects
>   that the method does not exist in one of the superclasses, then it
>   will generate an error.

So I would recommend reading the official document.